# React-slick with css modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I'm using webpack with css modules for my project and I've tried to install popular package react-slick to create slider. It works perfectly in sandbox, but in original project I have some difficulties.
When I'm, trying to import `slick.css` and `slick-theme.css` as mentioned in [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick) I got next error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css'
```

What I already tried to avoid this:

## 1

I installed

```
npm install file-loader url-loader --save
```

Updated my webpack.config.js by adding next section

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader:
      "style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded&" +
      "includePaths[]=" +
      path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules")
  }
```

Didn't Work

## 2

Replaced

```
import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

with

```
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
```

Didn't Work

## 3

I manually downloaded those two .css files in my project and import them directly from folder.

Didn't work.

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: did you install `slick-carousel`? (this is not part of `react-slick`)

Comment: Yeap, installed it before.

Comment: check my answer and update, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `slick-carousel` as well.
`react-slick` is only the Javascript part of the library, `slick-carousel` is the `css` part.

As per the [DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick):

```
npm install slick-carousel
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
```

**Update**
These imports are inside a css file, notice the `@` before the path.

So for example you got a `myStyles.css` file and there you can import the `slick-carousel` styles.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I still have this error after reinstalling slick-carousel

Comment: did you sort it out or still having problems?

Comment: when you use css modules you should import these files in global scope